# Use VBA Macro to print conditionally

Tags: excel, vba, printing, conditional-statements

Thanks in advance for your help. I have the following macro working:

```
Sub Macro1()

If Cells(3, 4) > 0 Then
Sheets("A-Lawn").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
End If
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is set up a condition where if the amount in column 4 is greater than $0, then it prints their individual excel sheet.  Below are the column headers and my first vendor's information.

```
Contractor  Sheet Name   PPW             Advances
Allen B     Abelcher     $7,947.60    $500.00
```

So, if Column 4 > 0, then print sheet listed in Column 2. I am so very new at this and appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of sheet names in the rows, the following would look at all the rows and print needed sheets:

```
    Sub Macro1()
    Dim lLastRow    As Long
    Dim i           As Integer
    lLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For i = 2 To lLastRow

        If Cells(i, 4) > 0 Then
            Sheets(Cells(i, 2).value).PrintOut copies:=1, collate:=True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```